# How to get rid of unknown border Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I've tried everything to get rid of these two border circled in the picture. But no matter what I do in css those two borders don't go and the weird thing is it's only on the right and bottom. Does anyone have a solution for this?

I'ts a QListWidget inside a Tab.

[image: Screenshot]

Edit: QSS code

```
QWidget{
background-color:#282828;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
}

QMainWindow{
border:0px;
background-color:white;
margin: 0px;
}
QListWidget{
    font: 25pt "Simplifica";
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight:100;
    background-color:#3A3A3A;
    color: white;
    alternate-background-color:#0C0032;
    margin: 0px;
}

QTabWidget{
font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
border: 0px;
background-color:#3A3A3A;
margin: 0px;
}

QTabBar::tab{
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
padding:5px;
}
QTabBar::tab:selected { 
color: white;
background-color:#190061;

}

QTabBar::tab:!selected {
color: white;
background-color: #282828;
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to help out with some sort of a code example referring to the styles which are used to generate what's shown in the screenshot. Can you provide a test link or the stylesheet & markup?

Comment: Okay I edited the original post with the css and more details. Thank you

Comment: For people that may have a similar issue use TabWidget:pane in css